# CompletableFuture dependent chain to run asynchronously

Tags: java-8, completable-future

How can I execute this full CompletableFuture chain to run asynchronously using a separate executor

```
  .thenApply(r -> {
            return validateStudents();
            })
  .thenCompose(r -> {
          return fetchAll(r);
            })
  .thenCompose(r -> {
          return processAll(r);
            })      
  .whenComplete((r, t) -> {

            });
    });
```

Comment: you want each method executed by async thread? or whole chain by one async thread ?

Comment: @Deadpool  whole chain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Async` methods from [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) with the default `ForkJoinPool`

> **All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool()** (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task)

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return "supplyAsync";
}).thenApplyAsync(supply->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"----"+supply);
    return "applyAsync";
}).thenComposeAsync(compose->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"----"+compose);
    return CompletableFuture.completedStage("composeAsync");

});
```

**Output :**

```
main
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3----supplyAsync
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3----applyAsync
```

You can also define custom thread pool and you can use that thread pool

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return "supplyAsync";
},pool).thenApplyAsync(supply->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"----"+supply);
    return "applyAsync";
},pool).thenComposeAsync(compose->{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"----"+compose);
    return CompletableFuture.completedStage("composeAsync");

},pool);
```

**Output :**

```
main
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1----supplyAsync
pool-1-thread-1----applyAsync
```